# jQuery 1.4.4 disable object & backwards compatibility of latest

Tags: jquery, object, compatibility

I'm working on a app that still utilizes jQuery v1.4.4
I'm trying to set an asp:Treeview object's enabled property, but 1.4.4 doesn't have the .attr function. I tried using the .attributes[x] function, but the disabled property seems to be ready only.

Is there another way of doing this in 1.4.4?

The alternate option is to upgrade to the latest jQuery library, but js in the app was written against the 1.4.4 library, would it be compatible with the latest library? Or would I have to rewrite some/most/all of the js in the application?

I'd love to just be able to use .removeattr('disabled');

Comment: So I guess upgrading your jQuery to a newer version is out of the question?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery 1.4.4 does have the attr function: http://api.jquery.com/attr/